# How to render a template with dynamic CSS?

Tags: django, django-templates, dynamic-css

I want to create a dynamic CSS file in a view and then render a template which loads that CSS file. Depending on the arguments given to the view, the CSS may have different values at certain places every time the view is called. How would I go about doing that? (I should add that I have no experience with writing files in Python/Django.)

Here is a simplified example of how I think it should work:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^myview/(?P<color>[0-9a-f]{6})/$', create_css_file),
)

# views.py
def create_css_file(request, color):
    raw = "@charset 'UTF-8';\n\n"
    raw += "body {\n"
    raw += "  color: #" + color + ";\n"
    raw += "}\n\n"

    f = open('mydynamic.css', 'r+')
    f.write(raw)

    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', locals())

# mytemplate.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{ f.name }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

For some reason, that doesn't work, although in the resulting HTML page's source code, it looks like the CSS file is loaded correctly. The `f` even arrives at the template correctly, because I can see its contents when I change the `<link>...` line to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{ f }}" />
```

(`f`instead of `f.name`). But the HTML is rendered without the desired color setting. Can anybody tell my why that is?

I suspected some path issue, and I toyed around quite a bit with different paths, but to no avail.

Please do not advise me to prepare several hardcoded CSS files (as I have found in answers to similar questions), because there will be several hundred possibilities.

Comment: is the link <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{ f }}" /> on click gives 404 error?

Comment: Erm, just put it in `<style>`? Writing to a file in a view like that is silly and will not work.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: At first glance, putting it in `<style>` seems to work, thank you! But since I want to learn, could you please elaborate as to why writing to a file in a view is silly and **why** it would not work? I've seen this being suggested somewhere else, but unfortunately without concrete instructions.

Comment: @Jo.: Because it writes to application's current working directory, which is unlikely to be anywhere near webroot (nor it should be), so the client will never be able to access it.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Ah, that makes sense, thanks. As I said, I'm new to the whole filewriting thing, but wouldn't it be possible to specify a directory in which to save the file? Maybe a directory that the client can also access?

Comment: @Jo.: Yes, but it's not a good idea anyway. It's an extra (and unnecessary) I/O operation per request, and concurrent requests might make it fail miserably, even if clients do have access to that file (consider one client that finished writing to the file, but haven't got around to fetching it yet, then another rewrites it with their own thing, and then the first one fetches it — bork'd).

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: I guess you're right, that would soon lead to chaos. Thanks for the explanation. Now that I know _why_ it's a bad idea I can let it go. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with @CatPlusPlus's suggestion: Calculating the necessary values in a view and passing the template a very long string (`raw`) which contains the entire CSS. In the template, I include it like so:

```
<style media="screen">{{ raw|safe }}</style>
```

Thanks everyone for your efforts!

Comment: Note: This can have unintended side effects since the browser and server will cache the inline CSS alongside the HTML. Sometimes (especially if your CSS is dynamic) you don't want to cache the CSS at all, let alone alongside the HTML.

Answer (score 13):

If you absolutely need to you can just create a css file dynamically.

You can create an entry in your urls.py. You can name urls anything you want this could look like a static .css file to the outside world but would be created dynamically.

```
(r'^(?P<color>[0-9a-f]{6})/dynamic.css$', dynamic_css)


def dynamic_css(request, color):
   """
   Create a css file based on a color criteria,
   or any other complicated calculations necessary
   """
   # do custom element positionting.
   return render_to_response('dynamic.css', {'color': color})


# dynamic.css    
body {
  background-color: {{ color }}
}
```

There is no reason to write css files for this.  Now you can just include

`<link rel="styleshee" type="text/css" href="/purple/dymamic.css" />`

In your template.

As mentioned this shouldn't be used just for changing one color.  That could be done in your template.  If you had to do something like this it would probably be a good idea to implement cacheing as every time a page is requested it has to dynamically generate .css that could be performance overhead.  This is more of an example to show you can name urls.py entries anything you want. And include them in any way you want in html ie. if you needed a custom javascript file dynamically created you could create an entry in urls.py and then create a view that generates a .js file.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and for clarifying that I can do much more with my URL conf than I thought. I'll keep that in mind for other occasions. As for the problem at hand I realize that dynamically creating a file is way too much trouble.

Answer (score 3):

views.py:

```
def create_css_file(request, color):
    f = color
    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', locals())
```

template:

```
<body style = "color:{{f}}!important;">
```

Don't create css file on the fly it is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If it were only about text color, I would do it as you suggested. Unfortunately, I have to perform several complex calculations in the view (like positioning depending on number of items and such) which result in different values in many different places in the CSS. That's why I want to create a CSS file on the fly.

Comment: @Jo is your dynamic css link in your template opening or giving 404 error

Comment: It is giving a 404 error at the moment. I've tried several different path constellations, and at some point I thought it was correct. The `f` in my question is the created file, and from the template's source code did show me its contents correctly, but the file was still not rendered correctly. Did I understand your question correctly? What path setting should I use to make it work? Maybe the template only loads CSS files which live within the `STATIC_URL` directory?

Comment: @jo save your css file where the STATIC_URL directory points to

Comment: @jo you can do complex stuff in the templates (for loops etc..). If that really is not enough then you can preprocess as much as possible in the view so the template is just outputting variables. Manual creation of files with django views is a bit like picking up a car and walking somewhere cause you don't like to drive.

Comment: Preprocessing the whole thing in a view is what I ended up doing. I then pass just one very long string to the template and put it in `style` tags as @CatPlusPlus suggested. I realize now that creating a dynamic CSS file is unnecessary in this case. (I really liked your car analogy...) Thanks!