# How to set image from models in css django 1.11.x?

Tags: python, css, django

I try insert a image previously registred by user in css file.

My model

```
class Basics(models.Model):
    ...
    logo = models.ImageField('Logo')
    ...
```

My context_processors

```
# -*- conding:utf-8 -*-

from .models import Basics

def general(request):
    try:
        sitebasics = Basics.objects.get(pk=1)
    except:
        sitebasics = False
    context =  {
        'sitebasics': sitebasics,
    }
    return context
```

My css file

```
  {% load thumbnail %}

  ...

  .header-full-title {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 75px;
    background-image: url("{{ sitebasics.logo|thumbnail_url:'logo_large' }}");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
  }
```

And the output inspecting the HTML is:

```
.header-full-title {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 75px;
    background-image: url({{ sitebasics.logo|thumbnail_url:'logo_large' }});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
```

So when render it don't put the path of image, puts `{{ sitebasics.logo|thumbnail_url:'logo_large' }}` as raw text from css.

How I did to load a image in css file when render HTML?

Comment: This isn't normally the way that you modify css classes. Is there a reason you are doing this in this manor? You would normally store css classes and  images in myproject/myproject/static/img and .../static/css  and then from html template {% load static %}  and  load the stylesheet and pull the desired image. You can even {% if test %} from within template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not render inside css.

If you want to change the background-image then better write inline inside template:

**Inside template:**

```
<div class="header-full-title" style="background-image: url('{{ sitebasics.logo|thumbnail_url:"logo_large" }}');"></div>
```

You can also create dynamic css, but it is not the case because you need to change only one property.

Comment: Are some properties with the same image but I post one exemple, and in css are more five `class` and `id` to do the same thing the diference is `with` and `height` image.

Comment: If you have multiple properties to change and also different elements for each you can change them then probably you can render css file dynamically. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10970037/709897